# How to create historical Gantt chart in Linux?

Tags: linux, charts, tex, gantt-chart

I need to create a Gantt timeline with dates from 19th century. Can anybody recommend a program that could handle that?

Answer (score 6):

Since you tagged it with [tex](/questions/tagged/tex), here's an approach using [`gantt.sty`](http://www.martin-kumm.de/tex/gantt.sty) from this page: [A LaTeX package for drawing gantt plots using `pgf`/`tikz`](http://www.martin-kumm.de/tex_gantt_package.php).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gantt}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
  \begin{landscape}
  \scalebox{0.8}{
  \begin{gantt}[xunitlength=0.5cm,fontsize=\small,titlefontsize=\small,drawledgerline=true]{10}{48}
    \begin{ganttitle}
      \titleelement{2009}{7}
      \numtitle{2010}{1}{2012}{12}
      \titleelement{2013}{5}
    \end{ganttitle}
    \begin{ganttitle}
      \numtitle{6}{1}{12}{1}
      \numtitle{1}{1}{12}{1}
      \numtitle{1}{1}{12}{1}
      \numtitle{1}{1}{12}{1}
      \numtitle{1}{1}{5}{1}
    \end{ganttitle}
    \ganttbar{task 1}{2}{17}
    \ganttgroup{a group of tasks}{6}{18}
    \ganttbar{task 2}{5}{10}
    \ganttbar[pattern=crosshatch,color=blue]{task 3}{15}{3}
    \ganttbar{task 4}{20}{3}
    \ganttcon{15}{4}{20}{6}
    \ganttbar{task 5}{15}{5}
    \ganttbarcon[color=red]{task 6}{20}{5}
    \ganttbarcon{task 7}{30}{5}
  \end{gantt}
  }
  \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

A similar approach using [`pstricks`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks) is provided by [`pst-gantt`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-gantt).

Answer (score 2):

[image] **GanttProject**

I have been using GanttChart a long time ago, it was pretty good for simple project scheduling (if this is what you want). It is still active and maintained. It's based on Java and works on Linux too.

The project web page is: [GanttProject.biz](http://www.ganttproject.biz/)

And the download page for the [latest release (2.5.2 as of writing)](https://code.google.com/p/ganttproject/downloads/list?can=2&q=label:Praha%20label:release&colspec=Filename%20Summary%20Uploaded%20ReleaseDate%20Size%20DownloadCount)

Answer (score 1):

Openproj can help you. But depends what you want, it doesn't work because it's prepared for Windows. Another simple program that you can use is called "Planner". That it's just for Linux.

Comment: Planner does not allow me to change the start project date before 1986.

Comment: Ok! So maybe you can try with the "Openproj" but there are some tools that don't work perfectly because the program is made for a Windows platform. But for a simple Gantt it's ok.

Comment: I finally settled for the gantt module for ConTeXt. It's very basic and rather "low level" but allows arbitrary texts to be used for labels.